# Token WebApi C# Auth

Tags: c#, entity-framework, oauth2

Estou emitindo token, porém no momento fazer uma requisição com o token, retorna a seguinte mensagem:

> "Message": "Authorization has been denied for this request."

Estou passando usuario e senha estática

Arquivo: **startup.cs**

```
private void ConfigureAccessToken(IAppBuilder app)
{
    var optionsConfigurationToken = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
    {
        //Permitindo acesso ao endereço de fornecimento do token de acesso sem 
        //precisar de HTTPS (AllowInsecureHttp). 
        //Em produção o valor deve ser false.
        AllowInsecureHttp = true,

        //Configurando o endereço do fornecimento do token de acesso (TokenEndpointPath).
        TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),

        //Configurando por quanto tempo um token de acesso já forncedido valerá (AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan).
        AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),

        //Como verificar usuário e senha para fornecer tokens de acesso? Precisamos configurar o Provider dos tokens
        Provider = new ProviderTokenAccess()
    };

    //Estas duas linhas ativam o fornecimento de tokens de acesso numa WebApi
    app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(optionsConfigurationToken);
    app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
}
```

Arquivo: **Provider**

```
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
{   

    var user = Users()
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == context.UserName
                        && x.Password == context.Password);

    if (user == null)
    {
        context.SetError("invalid_grant",
            "Usuário não encontrado ou a senha está incorreta.");
        return;
    }

    var identyUser = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
    identyUser.AddClaim(new Claim("sub", context.UserName));
    identyUser.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "user"));
    context.Validated(identyUser);
}

public static IEnumerable<User> Users()
{
    return new List<User>
    {
        new User { Name = "Marcelo", Password = "admin" },
        new User { Name = "Joao", Password = "12345" },

    };
}
```

Request

```
using System.Web.Http;

namespace PlataformaCliAPI.Controllers
{
    public class ContaController : ApiController
    {
        // GET: api/Conta       
        [Authorize]
        public string Get()
        {
            return "Sucesso";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Você tem um exemplo do request?

Comment: editei, incluindo o request;

Comment: Eu me referia ao produto, para você verificar se o token está sendo gerado e enviado

Comment: Leandro Angelo, não entendi, mas quando faço a requisição o token é gerado, tipo bearer.

Comment: É exatamente o que seria interessante você capturar, se o token está sendo gerado e incluído no bearer

Answer (score 0):

No seu arquivo **Startup.cs** troque o trecho:

```
app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(optionsConfigurationToken);
app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
```

por:

```
app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(optionsConfigurationToken);
```

Configure o CORS:
A configuração do CORS esta no pacote 'Microsoft.Owin.Cors'

```
app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
```

Remova as configurações Defaults da rota da API e adicione o trecho abaixo:

```
   config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
   config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
          name: "DefaultApi",
          routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
          defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }); 

app.UseWebApi(config);
```

---

No seu arquivo **Provider**

adicione o override:

```
   public override Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
        {
            context.Validated();
            return Task.FromResult(0);
```

### }

No seu arquivo **Web.config** (informação extra para não ter problema no ambiente de prod)

adicione:

```
<add key="OwinStartup" value="[NAMESPACE PARA STARTUP].Startup"/>
<add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="true" />
```

EXEMPLO de chamadas:

obtendo o token:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Chamando sua API passando o token

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Um dos problemas que identifiquei foi a linha invertida do meu método dentro da Startup.cs

Antes:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            var config = new HttpConfiguration();

            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                 name: "DefaultApi",
                 routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                 defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
             );

            app.UseWebApi(config);    
            ConfigureAccessToken(app);
        }
```

Depois, o certo:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            var config = new HttpConfiguration();

            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                 name: "DefaultApi",
                 routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                 defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
             );

            /*Essa linha precisa ser chamada antes do app.UseWebApi(config);*/
            ConfigureAccessToken(app);
            app.UseWebApi(config);
        }
```